# puedo ejecutar un comando de cmd de windows desde web?

Tags: php, html, cmd

si tengo una consola, puedo crear una aplicacion o algo como por ejemplo con c# qque ejecute comandos en mi consola de cmd dependiendo una web php ??
lei algo acerca de rcon password, dependiendo server pero no encuetro nada de informacion ;(

Answer (score 1):

Podes ejecutar comandos cmd directamente desde php con la funcion shel_exec.

por ejemplo:

```
echo shell_exec("dir");
```

te mostraría el contenido de la carpeta sobre windows.

Mas información de **shel_exec** [aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: gracias lei acerca de exec, pero como enlazo la consola de windows con mi web ?